# jQuery Checkbox - for multiple time iteration not working

Tags: jquery

I have a function, that iterate over a table and check some check boxes in a `<td>` , now this can be performed multiple time where the check boxes to select are different. But my problem is if i perform the step twice in a single instance , then the selection is not working properly, the table is inside a

```
<div>
<table> </table>
</div>
```

code for check box

```
// global
var selectedId  =""


function populate(Id){


if(selectedId != Id){

    selectedId = Id;

    // first uncheck previous selection if any 

    // selective  is the class of check box <td>
    // <td class="selective"><input type="checkbox" name="packId" 
    // value="${pack.packId}"></td>

    $('.selective input:checkbox').each(function () {
      var prevCheckedVal = (this.checked ? $(this).val() :"");
      if(prevCheckedVal != ""){
         $(this).find("input[type=checkbox]").attr("checked", false);
      }
    });

    // now select check boxes for present selection 
    $("tr.allVPClass").each(function() {
       $this = $(this)
       var catId = $this.find("input.IdInVpClass").val();
       if(selectedId == catId){
        $(this).find("input[type=checkbox]").attr("checked", true);
       }
    }); 
}
// open the dialoge
$("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
}
```

The table is populated in multiple div. if i open seperate div then its working , but not selecting/ checking any check box if i open a same div twice

Comment: it is not clear what you want to accomplish with your code, also you should explain a bit more the issue you're experiencing, what do you mean "open separate div"?

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the checked status you need to use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
$(this).find("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", false);
```

Also read [this](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/please-explain-attr-vs-prop-change-in-1-6) and [prop vs attr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Answer (score 0):

You should use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) for checkbox

```
$(this).find("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", true);
```